# How to create an exception page for file_get_contents when using header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

Tags: php

So I have a password protected folder on another website that I am trying to pull a PDF from to post on my cliet's website.  (Yes I do have permission from the third party to do this).  The file name includes a timestamp that is normally formatted to today's date, but sometimes they mess it up or miss a day; so, I need a fallback page for when this happens.

The problem is that I can not seem to figure out why it can't tell when it's getting a 404 error or not.

My code look like this right now:

```
<?php

$username="XXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXX";
$source="http://The/web/site/";
$thisPDF="todays%20report%20".date("F%20d%20Y").".pdf";
$thisfallback="fallback.html";
$url= $source.$thisPDF;
$fallbackURL = $source.$thisfallback;


$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
        )
));

$str = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $str;
if (strpos($str, 'HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') == false) {
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
        )
    ));
    $str = file_get_contents($fallbackURL, false, $context);
    echo $str;
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
        )
    ));

    $str = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $str;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `file_get_contents` you get the status code with:

```
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

that variable is reserved and filed after requesting the api.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

with that variable you can check if you get an 404 error or not and react on that.